# What happens to my flag weight if the author of the post I flagged got deleted before flag threshold reached? Ignored?

Tags: discussion, flag-weight, deleted-accounts

What will happen to my flag weight if user get deleted before flag threshold(6 flags) reached?

Looks like flags are just get ignored, but shouldn't that plus to our flag weights?

I am not serious about it, but just curious.

Example posts (all are spam posts, need 10k to view it)

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856813/free-sql-formatter-tool/5473346#5473346

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310168/best-place-to-purchase-site-templates/5287958#5287958
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572747/app-promo-site-iphone-app-website-template-in-landscape/5447994#5447994
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949962/django-blog-post-reply-system-display-replies/5443094#5443094
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949962/django-blog-post-reply-system-display-replies/5443120#5443120
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794232/django-view-returns-string-which-is-not-represented-correctly-in-html-template/5443159#5443159
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484390/list-display-names-from-django-models/5443187#5443187

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545358/what-e-commerce-platform-should-i-use-for-building-a-new-site/4995716#4995716
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965909/what-is-the-best-hosted-e-commerce-solution/5374646#5374646
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155725/whats-the-easiest-cheapest-solution-to-build-a-e-commerce-website/5374668#5374668

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576812/linux-certification/2400058#2400058

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342179/recommendations-or-discouragements-on-mcpd-asp-net-developer-v3-5-boot-camps/2346511#2346511
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480913/worth-of-getting-certified/2377370#2377370

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897119/tips-for-developing-an-rdp-application-for-android/5366846#5366846

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347306/is-there-a-sdk-that-i-can-download-to-do-in-app-purchase-for-android-blackberry-o/5349622#5349622

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639832/what-does-the-csrss-exe-process-do/5311173#5311173

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309618/subversion-web-based-browser/4484906#4484906
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565628/subversion-web-interface/4484809#4484809

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566367/php-email-form-sending-random-text/5150967#5150967

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392850/fullcalendar-dayclick-functionality/4522182#4522182
```

Comment: Do you mean "What happens to my flag weight if my user gets deleted"? Or "What happens to my flag weight if the author of the post I flagged got deleted"?

Answer (score 1):

You can't flag users directly, so I'm guessing you mean what happens if you flag the post of a user and result in the deletion of the user.

The answer to that is "nothing directly". The flag is still there post-user-deletion, as flags are not themselves tied to the author of the post they are attached to.

If you flagged for moderator attention, the flag still needs to be dismissed as valid or invalid (and if you caused an appropriate user deletion, you're likely to get it validated). If you flagged a spam/offensive post, then the flag weight change is based on what happened to the post, not the user. If the post gets deleted by a moderator or by community flagging, your flag weight will increase; if the post does not get deleted and the flag is cleared or ages away, your flag weight will decrease.

Comment: I have updated the post, looks like I was not cleared, I wanted to say that the flags that currently going on, not the one that successfully reached 6 flags and deleted

Comment: @YOU The answer to that is in my answer here - the flags continue to live. User deletion doesn't affect them.

Comment: @Grace, the flags continue to live but it will never reach threshold? that mean, you won't get flag-weight improvement. Is it reasonable?

Comment: @You The post can still get flagged if the user is deleted. And a moderator can still take whatever action necessary as well.

Comment: @Grace, hummm, ok. You're right. but its gone from flag list, and post got deleted, so may be nobody will bother to flag it?

Comment: @YOU If no one bothers to flag it, that's how it goes. But note that post deletion does tend to mark flags as valid.

Comment: @Grace, Yeah same idea here for post deletion, but I doubt that user deletion could be seperate process.

Comment: @YOU It *is* a separate process, I'll just tell you right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not matter on the author of the question rather it should be based on the questions itself.

Also since flag-weight does not have any recalc logic in itself, I think it will stay with you and does not get impacted by deleted question or author.

Comment: I think I was not cleared, I meant the flags that going on (not get reached 6th flags yet)

Comment: @YOU - Your flags will stay as @Grace has pointed out in his answer. It only depends on moderator approving or rejecting your flag. Depending on that, your flag-weight will increase/decrease. Should not matter if the post/author is deleted even when your flag is active.

Comment: according to my experiment, my flag weight didn't change on posts (in my question) I flagged. So I came up with this question.

Comment: @YOU - just a guess, I think your flag might still be pending to be processed yet? How are you sure that it has been processed completely by some mod? The flag-weight page does not indicate if the flag is pending or not.

Comment: you're right that I don't know it is pending or processed or not by moderator, but it is not first time I noticed, so I am assuming its really getting ignored. but ok, let me leave my question like this, I hope someone will come out to explain.